# Flush Assist Toilet Leaking

Tags: plumbing, toilet

I'm dealing with a constant leak in my flush assist toilet, which temporarily stops when I jiggle the handle, making a gurgling sound. The pressure cavity of the system looks complex, particularly a button with a screw on top. I'm unsure if tightening this screw is a correct approach.

Could anyone explain why the handle jiggle stops the leak or what the gurgling sound means? Is the button with the screw relevant to the leak, and how should I adjust it? Any detailed guidance, tips, or resources for a DIY fix would be greatly appreciated, though I'm open to professional advice if needed. Thanks in advance for your help!

Here is the model and serial number and I think the serial number "122713-F4K-1080" indicates that it was manufactured on December 27, 2013.
[image: happy flushmate.]

Comment: A pic of the inside of the tank will help.  Generally a handle "jiggle" makes the flush mechanism seat better.  Without a pic, we cannot tell you more accurately.

Comment: And how old is the unit? Do you use the cleaner pucks in the tank?

Comment: ok -- will get a pick -- and that will also get me the age of the unit. Not, I don't use cleaner pucks (or know what those are).

Comment: so serial number "122713-F4K-1080" indicates that it was manufactured on December 27, 2013. no, I don't use cleaner pucks but will if that fixes the problem. @RMDman do you want a full pic of the tank -- I don't see anything other than there is a small bit of water in the bottom of the tank.

Comment: greatly appreciate your help. we are losing a lot of $$ as this keeps running. We always try to jiggle the handle a lot, but sometimes my kids forget.